# Django filter through multiple fields of related model

Tags: django, filter

I have three models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Name', max_length=100, unique=True, db_index=True)

class Recipe(models.Model):
    pass

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, verbose_name='Recipe', db_index=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, verbose_name='Product')
    amount = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Amount', max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
```

How can I filter Recipe objects that have only the given Ingredients with the given amounts?

For ex., I need Recipes that have only the following inredients:

- id = 1 and amount <= 10, and
- id = 2 and amount <= 15.

If there are any other ingredients, those recipes shouldn't be returned by query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make queries that [span through relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) and make complex queries with [q object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q). For example, in your case.

```
Recipe.objects.filter(Q(Q(ingredient_set__id=1, ingredient_set__amount__lte=10) | Q(ingredient_set__id=2, ingredient_set__amount__lte=15)))
```

Comment: How can I exclude items that have other ingredients?

Comment: audciz, [see Q's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)    You can use the `~` to negate a `Q` object and you can combine them with other `Q` objects using bitwise `&`.